# How to paginate Views page display?

Tags: drupal, view, pagination

So, Ive been making websites in Drupal for over 2 years now, but I'm profoundly stuck using Drupal Views module and paginating a page display. Basically I'm picking up a bunch of articles, sorting them by their date published and am limiting it to only 10 items per page, but I dont see a "More Link" and I have never tried to do paginating in Drupal. Any help would be great, thanks!

[alt text http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/562/drupalpaginate1.png](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/562/drupalpaginate1.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to adjust the "use pager" setting. It is currently set to "no".

Comment: Wow. That did it. Next time ill take it a bit slow, and try not to freak out. Hopefully, this will help others who dont realize it. Thanks! I appreciate the help!